# Filtering out two columns in a dataset in R to check for result

Tags: r, dataframe, dataset

I am using a dataset of movie lens in R and I am trying to filter out the movies that are both thriller and the ratings are above 4, and i can not figure out how i  will join  the RateMovies and RateNames together.

```
    Thriller <- which(movielens$genres == "Thriller")
    ThriName <- movielens$title[Thriller]
    
    RateMovies <- movielens$rating > 4
    
    RateNames <- movielens$title[RateMovies]
```

Comment: `subset(movielens, genres == "Thriller" & rating > 4)`

Comment: Than you , this worked but there are some movies that have up to 3 genres , and i will like for a movie with both comedy and thriller with a rating > 4 to show too